# a list with different css classes and php query

Tags: php, css

I have this php query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{

   echo "<ul>";

   echo "<li>{$row['title']}</li>";

   echo "</ul>";

}
```

and my xhtml code is:

```
<ul>
<li class="pdn5">one</li>
<li class="pdn5">two</li>
<li class="no-pdn">three</li>
</ul>
```

In this case, how can write the php loop?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{
   echo "<li class='some_class'>{$row['title']}</li>";
}
   echo "</ul>";
```

*Update for class name of li element:*

If your want to add specific classes for each of the list element, you can, for example, store this class name in DB and retrieve it with your title. Or it's also possible to make class name, based on the $row['title'] value. For example:

```
echo "<li class='li_".$row['title']."'>{$row['title']}</li>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the last row to be the only one with "no-pdn", then you could use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{    
   echo "<ul>";    
   echo '<li class="'.($i < $numRows ? 'pdn5' : 'no-pdn').'">'
         .$row['title']."</li>";
   echo "</ul>";
   i++;
}
```